# Single unified argument vs specific arguments in Java (>= 7)

Tags: java, interface, argument-passing

I'm designing a code which involves one Master Class which fans out the input request to multiple implementations of some interface. Note that each implementation has different arguments. (Ex. in case of calculating CreditReliability of a person, one implementation might not care about gender but some other implementation might use it). Also, fetching an input can be thought of as a cache lookup.

I can either pass a big unified object to all the implementations and leave it to them to chose what they require and ignore the rest. This makes the signature bloated and the code, in general, less readable. However, if I write a new layer which converts the master object to implementation specific argument object, it might lead to performance issues due to large number of objects created and duplication of effort (Ex. age might be fetched by 3 out 5 implementations which would lead to 3 cache lookups instead of 1 in case of a unified argument).

Does someone know a clean way of implementing the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass different arguments in constructor, which differs for each implementation, and leave same arguments in method parameters:

```
public interface SomeAction {
    int doSomething(int arg);
}

public class ActionOne implements SomeAction {
    public ActionOne() {}

    @Override
    public int doSomething(int arg) {
        return arg * 10;
    }
}

public class ActionTwo implements SomeAction {

    private boolean someSpecificArgument;

    public ActionTwo(boolean someSpecificArgument) {
        this.someSpecificArgument = someSpecificArgument;
    }

    @Override
    public int doSomething(int arg) {
        if (someSpecificArgument) {
            return arg * 1000;
        } else {
            return arg * 10;
        }
    }
}
```

So now you have:

```
new ActionOne().doSomething(5);
new ActionTwo(true).doSomething(5);
```

The idea is that `ActionOne` has one argument (`int`), and `ActionTwo` has two arguments (`boolean`, `int`).

It's hard to make good example, so you can provide your own code for us for better understanding situation.